# css issue after enabling the angular cli routing

Tags: angular, angular-cli

**Issue details**

There is just one route in the code and that is the default route for login component. Due to this line of code `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` which is present in the app.component.html, my html gets disturbed. there is no problem, if the parent div tag in the login component comes directly inside this div `<div class="row justify-content-center">`. Is there any way to fix this as there are other component with different classes at their root.

**code in app-routing-module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {LoginComponent} from './auth/login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        component: LoginComponent,
        path: ''
    }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**code in app.component.html**

```
<header></header>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Code in Login.component.html**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <main class="py-4">
    </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply some class to the root level of LoginComponent you can use the [host](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#host) property (based on [inheritance](https://angular.io/api/core/Component#inherited-from-directive-decorator)):

```
@Component({
    selector: "app-login",
    templateUrl: "./login.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./login.component.css"],
    host: {
        class: "col-md-4",
    },
})
export class LoginComponent {...}
```

The result output:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <app-login class="col-md-4">...</app-login>
</div>
```

Comment: I was looking to set class to the component tag when the route == login, can it be done?

Comment: @Pankaj updated the answer to work only with classes.